Designing a particular clock cycle series with glue logic/CMOS/TTL for serial data without a uP
I am looking to design an interface for serial data that runs for 31 cycles (not 32, I know), but with uneven cycles to transmit serial data. Each cycle is 8 clock pulses (at 7MHz). For the first 20 cycles (160 clock pulses) the data needs to be held high, then low for 2 cycles (16 pulses), then the last 9 cycles (72 pulses) can be made up of random pulses. So:
20 cycles/160 pulses: high
2 cycles/16 pulses: low
9 cycles/72 pulses: random
Here is the timing diagram:

For the data cycle I assume a divide by 8 (using a CD4040) will work. The 8 bits are what I'm looking to control here (the aforementioned high/low/random setup).
I am decently familiar with CMOS/TTL glue logic (or at least rudimentary knowledge and connections), so my assumption is that - while perhaps cumbersome - this is possible. I would like to accomplish this with CMOS/TTL rather than a uP/microprocessor.
Clock dividers, flip flops, and gates are my guess as to what it will take (at a minimum), but as to how to implement it I'm at a bit of a loss. Any suggestions?

Sounds like a job for two cascaded 74LS163A and a bit of clever decoding logic.

@JonathanS. interesting idea! After posting the question I had a thought to use something like a 4021/4094 and cascade them and pull each respective output high or low as needed - is something like that possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

@JonathanS. actually nevermind, the 4021/4094 wouldn't work because the outputs are parallel not serial - whoops. How would you suggest I start with the 74*163s?

Do the requirements allow using programmable logic, such as a CPLD, rather than having to connect multiple CMOS/TTL devices? Writing the logic in VHDL or Verilog could be simpler.

@ChesterGillon a CPLD would certainly be easier ha ha, but this is more of a proof-of-concept/showing it can be done sort of thing!

You can use two cascaded 74x163 to build a synchronous (and resettable / loadable) 8-bit up-counter. After that, feed the counter value into three 74x682 magnitude comparators to determine in which phase of the serial transmit cycle you are (compare with 159, 175, 247). This gives you three "greater-than" outputs.
Then build the following discrete logic (with a multiplexer for example, or just a couple of gates):

If the >159 signal is inactive, output high.
If the >159 signal is active and >175 is inactive, output low.
If the >175 signal is active and >247 is inactive, output data.
Outside of the mux: If >247 is active, reset the counter (to restart the transmission) or disable it (to pause until an external restart trigger comes in). You can also use this signal to load new parallel data to be transmitted.

To output the actual serial data, you could use something like a chain of 74x165 shift registers. The enable signal to the shift registers would be: (>175) & !(>247) & Ctr0 & Ctr1 & Ctr2, where CtrN is the Nth lowest bit of the counter value. All you need is a large AND gate and an inverter. This ensures that the data is only shifted every 8th clock cycle during the data phase. The output serial signal of the shift register must then be fed into the mux mentioned above to generate the final serial frame.
All synchronous devices should be attached directly to the same clock to avoid issues (like clocking on glitches), which in this case would be 7 MHz. This is perfectly doable with 74HC / 74HCT logic.

This is an excellent response, though I'll ha e to take some time and digest it all! The magnitude comparator seems a bit difficult to come by (readily available, but a bit more esoteric), so I'll order a few to see how it goes (already have most of the other logic ICs). Thank you!

160 + 16 + 72 equals 248, which is less than 256.  Thus, all of the necessary timing starts and stops can be derived by one 8-bit counter plus gating logic.  Note that all of the periods still are divisible by 2.  If you pre-divide by one bit,
80 + 8 + 36 = 124  Now you are down to a 7-bit counter plus decoding.
Add another bit to the pre-divider, and
40 + 4 + 18 = 62
Now you are down to a 6-bit counter plus decoding.  Doing it again,
20 + 2 + 9 = 31
This is as low as this concept can go, a single 8-bit divider with decoding logic driven by the last 5 bits.
Because all of the desired decoded states come after the 16th count, one way to do the decoding is with one 4-line-to-16-line decoder with an Enable input (74154 or equiv.).  With this, you get a clean pulse at the start and stop times of every one of the required states.  Use states 4, 6, and 15 to control the other circuit actions.
One way to do that is to use the decoded pulses to set and reset flipflops.  For example, the CD4043/4044 each have four flipflops, and you need only three.

Another excellent response - thank you! I'll have to scrounge up the 74154 or thereabout to try this out. Any IC you would recommend for the 8-bit divider, or are you suggesting using the divide by 8 output of say a CD4040, etc.?

At 7 MHz, the ripple delay through 8 stages could approach one clock period (depending on the speed of the counter).  Because of this, I'd go with a synchronous counter.  That rules out the 4020, 24, 40, 60, etc.
